# Match unknown substring with RegEx

Tags: regex, linux, sed, grep

How can I get an unknown substring with an regular expression? I know what's before and after the wanted string but I don't want the known part with in the result.

Example text:

```
jhgjgjgvocher_SOMETHINGHERE.dbhjjkghjkg
vocher_SOMETHINGELSE.db
```

I'm looking for 'SOMETHINGHERE' and 'SOMETHINGELSE' only.

`vocher_` and `.db` are always before and after the relevant part but should not be in the result.

A working solution is:

```
cat test | egrep -o "vocher_.*\.db" | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1
```

… but you know it's ugly.

Is it possible to search exactly for an unknown part with regex (in this case only the `.*` part), or do I need to use something like sed? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Try replacing `egrep -o "vocher_.*\.db"` with  `grep -oP "(?<=vocher_).*?(?=\.db)"`

Comment: @Wiktor: Right, but no need for the question mark after the asterisk.

Comment: @JosefScript The non-greedy `*?` is required for input that looks like `vocher_SOMETHINGHERE.dbblahvocher_SOMETHINGELSE.dbblah`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution using perl is the following:

```
perl -ne 'if (/vocher_(.*)\.db/){ print "$1\n";}' test_file.txt
```

This iterates line-by-line over the file and only prints the desired portion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following ***grep*** approach:

```
grep -Po '(?<=vocher_).+(?=\.db)' test
```

`-P` - allows Perl regular expressions

`-o` - prints only matched substrings

The output will be like below:

```
SOMETHINGHERE
SOMETHINGELSE
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it does not exploit the additional information OP has in his problem. He wants `voucher_` to precede the desired text and the file should be a `.db`. If you used this code, you would get everything after an underscore, regardless of whether it met the other conditions.

Comment: @ahjohnston25, I've read the question again and fixed my solution, now it's fine